# bash: ./checksetup.pl: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, bugzilla

While installation of bugzilla I was running this commmand, /.checksetup.pl , but I am getting the error,

```
bash: ./checksetup.pl: No such file or directory
```

I am using centos v6.5.

Comment: Is there actually a script named `checksetup.pl` in the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you in the right place (u can use 'ls' command and see if it's showing 'checksetup.pl' )

it might be not executable ,then try this :

```
sudo chmod +x checksetup.pl
```

Comment: If the file was not executable, bash would throw `Permission denied`.

Comment: did you saw the file when you execute the 'ls' command ?

Comment: yes I used ls command -ls command, but its not showing checksetup.pl

Comment: And I am using this command in this folder, /var/www/html , and I also checked in /usr/bin/perl/ using ls command but I didn't find.

Comment: you should check if "checksetup.pl" exist in the bugzilla folder perhaps "/var/www/html/bugzilla/"

Comment: Yes it is, thanks ImadOS.